# Page displays blank after rendering the table with columns in react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to the react developement. I am trying to create a table that displays json content recieved from an api. i have used two js one is App.js and another is form.js.. Below is the code

### form.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Table} from "react-bootstrap";



class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',          
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(recievedJson => {
            this.setState({posts: recievedJson})
        })
    }

    
    render(){
       
        const columns =  [
            {
                Header: "User ID",
                accessor: "userId"

            },
            {
                Header: "ID",
                accessor: "id"

            },
            {
                Header: "Title",
                accessor: "title"

            },
            {
                Header: "Content",
                accessor: "body"

            }

        ]

        return( 

           <Table columns={columns} data= {this.state.posts} />
   
        )
    }

}


export default Form;
```

And App.js

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import Form from './components/form'




function Welcome () { 

  const [region, setRegion] = useState([
    {Name: 'Kochi', status: '23 ° C'},
    {Name: 'Khanna', status: '29 °C'},
    {Name: 'Kollam', status: '24 °C' }
  ])

    return(
     <div className="app" >
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Form />
    </div>
    );
  
          }

export default Welcome;
```

### Actual

```
The page not rendering the table defined with the columns
```

I searched for the solution, but that didn't helped me in my case

Appreciate if anybody can help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure columns={columns} and data = {this.state.posts} in ReactTable component, are its children and not its props?

Comment: Hi Sandip .. i am not sure about this.. but somehow i manged to use the Table from  react-bootstrap, but now i dont see the table as well as the coloumns ? I just updating the question with the changes i done